# C# ASP.NET Core Identity регистрация в DI UserManager, RoleManager без вызова AddIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Есть отдельный WebApi проект над базой данных пользователей "UserDbWebApi", которую использует проект для авторизации на `IdentityServer4`  "IdentityServerApi_AspNetIdentity".

Для предоставления CRUD операция к "UserDbWebApi", также нужна регистрация через IdentityServer4 (Только пользователь с ролью SuperAdmin может иметь доступ к этому api).
Пользователи хранятся в удобном виде `ApplicationUser` наследованном от IdentityUser (ASP.NET Core Identity).
Проблема в том что система аутентификации `ASP.NET Core Identity` перекрывает система аутентификации `IdentityServer4`.

Для удобства работы с БД пользователей `ASP.NET Core Identity` предполагает использовать удобные сервисы над EF:

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser>
RoleManager<ApplicationUser>
```

для их регистрации в DI нужно подключить

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

После этого сервисы доступны через DI по всему проекту.

Но вызов `AddIdentity` также подключает авторизацию `ASP.NET Core Identity` и доступ с токеном выданным `IdentityServer4` уже не работает.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
      //Доступ работает только с токеном выданным IdentityServer4
    }
}
```

В итоге для нормальной работы авторизации `AddIdentity` мне подключать не нужно, но нужны сервисы `UserManager`, `RoleManager`.
Как их зарегить в `DI`?
В лоб не работает

```
  services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
  services.AddScoped<RoleManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Или как отключить авторизация используя `AddIdentity`?

Или все таки придется отказаться от UserManager, RoleManager и работать напрямую с контекстом EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно явно указать систему авторизации в атрибуте. Использовать Cookie для AspNetIdentity или использовать Bearer для моего случая авторизации через выданный токен. [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
Вот и все! и можно подключать сервисы AddIdentity.